# I want .Trim to remove the specific characters from my whole string. (C#)

Tags: trim

I want to use Trim to remove some specific characters from a string. The problem is that it only removes the first specific character of it, but I want it to go through the whole string. This is the code:

```
string mySt1 = mySt2.Trim('a', 'b', 'c');
```

So if mySt2 is 'a b c d' for example, it removes the letter 'a' only.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does your code compile?  I'm a little surprised if it does, because in C#, the Trim Method does not need arguments ('a', 'b', 'c').  It sounds like mySt2 ends up as " b c d".  Is that right?

The answer to your question "What could be the problem?" appears in the Microsoft definition of the Trim Method, in the Remarks section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx

> > The Trim Method removes from the current string all leading and trailing white-space characters.  Each leading and trailing trim operation stops when a non-white-space character is encountered.

So in your case, once Trim finds the first 'a', it strips off the first 'a' and returns the rest of the string.  It doesn't go any farther because the 'b' and 'c' arguments are ignored.

If you want to remove multiple single characters that appear anywhere within a string, you will probably need to use a combination of Methods.  I don't have a C# compiler, so I can't write code for you.  But I have written plenty of string manipulation code in many languages (Pascal, Snobol, Python, C, etc), so I can give you a possible sequence of steps, using Methods from Microsoft's C# String Methods page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_Methods(v=vs.110).aspx.

> > For each specific character to delete in a string, do while Step 1 finds the specific character to delete in the string.
> >
> > 1. Find the next occurrence of the character you're looking for, if any; (IndexOf(Char))
> > 2. Concatenate the characters BEFORE the character to delete, with the characters AFTER the character to delete, and save the resulting string.  (String.Remove Method (Int32, Int32))

So, in the end, given the string " Abracadabra shazam!  ", if you want to delete all ('a', 'b', 'c')s (but not blanks), your code would leave you with " Ardr shzm!  " (notice that 'A' != 'a').

Visit the Remove Method page and see the Example to get the idea, and learn the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Replace. Something like this should work:

```
var mySt1 = mySt2.Replace(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'}, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the replace method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string mySt1 = mySt2
    .Replace("a", string.Empty)
    .Replace("b", string.Empty) 
    .Replace("c", string.Empty);
```